# Using Stokes theorem on a discontinuous function

Tags: vector-analysis, contour-integration, stokes-theorem

I've a vector function whose curl is well defined inside and outside,except on the boundary

$\mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{H}=\mathbf{J}_{f}$

I'm interested in using stokes theorem across the boundary (i.e the area on which I apply the theorem resides both inside and outside the boundary
) and I'll get
$$\oint \mathbf{H} \cdot d \mathbf{l}=I_{f_{\mathrm{enc}}}$$

Will the closed loop integral be valid that'll result from the application of stokes theorem, notwithstanding that the function from which it was derieved had a discontinuity at the boundary?